# Android: How to get map snapshot?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show map snapshot without displaying the actual map on the UI. I am sucessfull in getting the snapshot after the map is loaded to the UI. So I just want to know if it's possible to load the map in the background and get the snapshot and just display that snapshot on the UI, something like google now.

Comment: no i dont think its possbile, you wil have to show the view to get the snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your asking about, Static Maps by Google

Static maps gives your the *map snapshot* by specifying the place where the map has to be shown and the size of the map.

Eg:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300
[image: This maps shown Brooklyn as center with size of 600x300]

**This maps shown Brooklyn as center with size of 600x300**

Refer [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) for more apis and examples.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to take the static map

```
String url = String.format(
        "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=%f,%f&zoom=16&size=%dx300&sensor=false&key=%s",
        lat,
        lon,
        imageWidth,
        context.getResources().getString(R.string.mapApiKey2)
    );

    Bitmap bmp = null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

    InputStream in;
    try {
        in = httpclient.execute(request).getEntity().getContent();
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bmp;
```

substitute lat, lon and imageWidth and this returns you a bmp.
create a function with this code in it